# Sufficient condition for existence of Neumann problem for Laplace equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

First, which of the following, concerning the solution of the Neumann problem for the Laplace equation,
$$\Delta u=0~ \text{on}~~\Omega, \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=f(x,y),\text{on}~\partial\Omega$$
on a smooth bounded domain $\Omega$ is true ?

$1$. Solution is unique.

$2$. Solution is unique up to an additive constant .

$3$. Solution is unique up to multiplicative constant.

$4$. No conclusion can be drawn about uniqueness.

I know that the result is **if solution exists for Neumann problem then solution is unique up to additive constant**. So can I say that option $D$ is correct option ?

**Secondly** I know only necessary condition for existence of solution of the Neumann problem $$\Delta u=0~ \text{on}~~\Omega, \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=f(x,y),\text{on}~\partial\Omega$$ which is $\int_{\partial\Omega}fds=0$ for bounded domain . I want to know sufficient condition for existence of solution for this Neumann problem . I searched in my local books but didn’t get any exact answer for sufficient condition. There is also [necessary and sufficient condition for the Poisson's equation to admit a solution$?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2081403/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-the-poissons-equation-to-admit-a-solutio) Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Why "Option D" and not 2.?

Comment: @DanDoe solution may not exist ??

Comment: @DanDoe before uniqueness firstly solution must exist .

Comment: The solution to your problem is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214541/necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-the-solution-of-neumann-problem

Comment: @JosePérezCano ok thank you . I will see this question.